# How can a local program access the hdfs directory?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, snort

How can a local program access the hdfs directory? I have a local program installed on all my Hadoop nodes. The local program runs from the terminal therefore I'm using Java's Runtime Execution API in my map reduce program.

I just want to know on how my local program can access the hdfs directory. Please Note, Copying the file to my local FS is not a solution to what I have to achieve. Hence, need to access the files as they are in the HDFS.

P.S. The local program is Snort, and the HDFS files are splitted Pcap files

Comment: Do you want to know about hadoop java client or its working behind the seen?

Answer (score 0):

For Java program, your could use `generic FileSystem interface` to access HDFS.

> Hadoop’s org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem is generic class to access
>   and manage HDFS files/directories located in distributed environment.
>   [Hadoop HDFS JAVA API](http://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/08/16/hadoop-hdfs-java-api/)